# Axios dosen't send request

Tags: javascript, axios

I'm trying to send a request to my express application with Axios in javascript, but it's not working and every time it just returning undefined for data.data.message in then case.
but I'm sure about the URL and also I checked my application log but my server isn't receiving any requests
here is my Axios method in JS file, is there anything wrong with it?

```
const sendCode = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios({
      url: `/auth/email/sendcode`,
      method: "POST",
    })
      .then((data) => {
        resolve(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        reject(err);
      });
  });
};
```

Comment: Can you post the api that you are calling?

Comment: Did you check if this request if it's working in postman

Comment: I hope you configured the base URL correctly.

Comment: I was restricted the API route just for the admins and I was sending the request with a Non-admin user. that was why the server was rejecting the request, just a silly mistake by me :)

Answer (score 0):

Unrelated to your problem but for your information, you can directly use

```
const sendCode = () => axios({
    url: `/auth/email/sendcode`,
    method: "POST",
});
```

Since it will also return Promise object.

Answer (score 0):

```
const sendCode = () => {
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios.post(`/auth/email/sendcode`)
      .then((data) => {
        return resolve(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        return reject(err);
      });
  });
};
```

or you can use async-await

```
const sendCode = async () => {
  const response = await axios.post(`/auth/email/sendcode`)
  return response
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your answer, I notice that you are missing the body ("data") for your POST request.

```
const sendCode = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios({
      url: `/auth/email/sendcode`,
      method: "post",
      data: {
        // Your request data here
      }
    })
    .then((data) => {
      resolve(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      reject(err);
    });
  });
};
```

If this fails then you will have to give us a *more elaborate* question regarding how you are calling this API.

NOTE: Since Axios already returns a promise, you can remove the new PRomise to something like this;

```
const sendCode = () => axios({
      url: `/auth/email/sendcode`,
      method: "post",
      data: {
        // Your request data here
      }
    });
```

The second solution is for you to avoid unnecessary code and confusion that may arise from so many promises.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use async-await to make it more readable

```
const sendCode = async () => {
  const response = await axios.post(`/auth/email/sendcode`)
  return response
};
```